# web application deployment in weblogic failure : Proxy authentication failure

Tags: java, http, web, proxy, weblogic11g

I'm trying to deploy a web application in **weblogic 11g** server. When I deploy this application, weblogic is throwing following error(*Stack trace is below*).

Once I hit the URL of this application, it has to create a SOAP message and hit a cloud application using HTTPS protocol. We have a proxy server in between. When I hit the URL of web application it takes some time and browser respond with blank page(500). I checked weblogic server log and found this exception. Also I have set the system properties for proxy with required proxy IP and port in the web application while creating the URL to hit the cloud application.
I am not able the find the exact issue. Went through many online forum and post and tried many solution. Could not find an exact solution. I'm new to weblogic server. Do not have much idea about this. Was all ready with the web application to deploy in tomcat server. At the last moment client came up with webloigc server and a proxy server in between. Any suggestions and comments will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Proxy or Server Authentication Required
at weblogic.socket.utils.ProxyUtils.getAuthInfo(ProxyUtils.java:279)
at weblogic.socket.utils.ProxyUtils.getProxySocket(ProxyUtils.java:199)
at weblogic.socket.utils.ProxyUtils.getSSLClientProxy(ProxyUtils.java:239)
at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.newSSLClientSocket(SocketMuxer.java:397)
at weblogic.socket.JSSESocketFactory.getConnectedSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:92)
at weblogic.socket.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:65)
at weblogic.security.SSL.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:140)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.openServer(HttpsClient.java:289)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.openServer(HttpsClient.java:363)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:518)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.getHttpClient(HttpsURLConnection.java:330)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:450)
<our custom methods are here to create SOAP XML to hit a cloud application>
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3732)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is explained in the Oracle documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53672_01/doc.111191/e53673/GUID-36A18CFA-55F1-4D19-B371-A6D15EBF2E24.htm

As you are using SSL/TLS, you should use https.proxyHost and https.proxyPort instead of http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort

Comment: Yes I'm using SSL. For this we have implemented https.proxyHost and https.proxyPort in our web application. Also tried altering the setDomain file in the weblogic server. But nothing has worked so far.